# I think the SDL tag system is kind of broken. [sdl], [sdl-1.2] and [sdl-2] are too weird

Tags: discussion, tags, versions

So, SDL is *[Simple DirectMedia Layer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_DirectMedia_Layer)*. I won't bother explaining when the Wikipedia guys have already done the hard work.

The idea of [sdl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sdl), [sdl-1.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sdl-1.2) and [sdl-2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sdl-2) is:

[sdl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sdl): General SDL. No specific version.
[sdl-1.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sdl-1.2): For SDL 1.2.
[sdl-2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sdl-2): For SDL 2.

It seems right except SDL 1.2 is deprecated and SDL 2 is mostly incompatible with SDL 1.2. The weirder problem is that SDL 1 stuff and SDL 2 stuff are seen as completely different things. This is similar to Python 2.7 and Python 3, but not the same. There are many SDL 2 questions tagged with [sdl2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sdl2) but not with [sdl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sdl). And other questions are tagged with [sdl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sdl) but not with [sdl2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sdl2). This is pretty weird.

### First question

I need some clarification about how an SDL question should be tagged. Is it enough to tag [sdl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sdl) or is the version tag [sdl2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sdl2) or [sdl1.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sdl1.2) also necessary? Or is only the version tag enough? [sdl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sdl) implies SDL 2 if no version tag is present because SDL 1.2 is deprecated.

### Second question

So, how is it different from Python? Python 4 is nowhere near, but SDL 3 is kind of planned. There's a "placeholder" milestone with a single issue (a feature request) at *[Milestones - libsdl-org/SDL](https://github.com/libsdl-org/SDL/milestones)*. Uh... what does this imply? What will happen to questions which are only tagged with [sdl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sdl) which are about [sdl2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sdl2)? SDL 2 will be deprecated and then [sdl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sdl) will start to mean SDL 3 and then all those SDL 2 questions will be mistagged.

I think the solution is to make it explicitly clear that [sdl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sdl) will not imply that it's specifically SDL 2 even though SDL 1.2 is deprecated.

However, SDL 3 is nowhere near the horizon. Am I just too prudent for Stack Overflow standards?

Comment: How about the other way: remove version specific tags and leave a generic one. Also, as someone that has dealt with SDL libraries, anything before 2.x is basically worthless, since anything that would need SDL, supports version 2 and vendors kinda solved the upgrade path by releasing a compat library. (Heck, on Debian no package depends on it)

Comment: @Braiam You're right. We don't need SDL1.2. People have been given enough time to update their code.

Comment: Except for that one guy working in a government-funded cube farm that is not allowed to upgrade to 2 and needs to look up SDL 1.2 answers. Speaking as someone who frequently gets called in to support ancient projects built on fragile frameworks built on standards-before-they-were-standards, please consider those poor bastards before updating the tag system. It will take you literally one more keystroke to type [sdl2] instead of [sdl].

Comment: @HereticMonkey So better "deprecate" the tag [sdl] and tell people to only use [sdl-1.2] and [sdl-2].